# FusionCharts multiple array via SQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, fusioncharts

I am attempting to generate a line graph using FusionCharts via an SQL query and PHP wrapper. I cannot figure out how to get another dataset into the graph and render it. I assume I will require two SQL queries and then somehow load them into the array? Attached is my code.

```html
<?php

/* Include the `fusioncharts.php` file that contains functions    to embed the charts. */

   include("includes/fusioncharts.php");

/* The following 4 code lines contain the database connection information. Alternatively, you can move these code lines to a separate file and include the file here. You can also modify this code based on your database connection. */

   $hostdb = "127.0.1.1";  // MySQl host
   $userdb = "test";  // MySQL username
   $passdb = "test";  // MySQL password
   $namedb = "weather";  // MySQL database name

   // Establish a connection to the database
   $dbhandle = new mysqli($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb, $namedb);

   /*Render an error message, to avoid abrupt failure, if the database connection parameters are incorrect */
   if ($dbhandle->connect_error) {
      exit("There was an error with your connection: ".$dbhandle->connect_error);
   }
?>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>Chart Development</title>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

      <!-- You need to include the following JS file to render the chart.
      When you make your own charts, make sure that the path to this JS file is correct.
      Else, you will get JavaScript errors. -->

      <script src="fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js"></script>
  </head>

   <body>
      <?php

         // Form the SQL query that returns the results
         $strQuery = "select AVG(temperature) as avgtemp, AVG(humidity) as avghum, MONTHNAME (date) as date FROM data WHERE date BETWEEN '2008-01-01' AND '2016-01-01' GROUP BY MONTH (date) ORDER BY MONTH (date) ASC";

         // Execute the query, or else return the error message.
         $result = $dbhandle->query($strQuery) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");


         // Form the SQL query that returns the results
         $strQuery2 = "select AVG(humidity) as avghum, MONTHNAME (date) as date FROM data WHERE date BETWEEN '2008-01-01' AND '2016-01-01' GROUP BY MONTH (date) ORDER BY MONTH (date) ASC";

         // Execute the query, or else return the error message.
         $result2 = $dbhandle->query($strQuery2) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");


         // If the query returns a valid response, prepare the JSON string
         if ($result) {
            // The `$arrData` array holds the chart attributes and data
            $arrData = array(
                "chart" => array(
                  "caption" => "Averages Per Month",
                  "paletteColors" => "#6c7377",
                  "bgColor" => "#ffffff",
                  "borderAlpha"=> "20",
                  "canvasBorderAlpha"=> "0",
                  "usePlotGradientColor"=> "0",
                  "plotBorderAlpha"=> "10",
                  "showXAxisLine"=> "1",
                  "xAxisLineColor" => "#999999",
                  "showValues" => "0",
                  "divlineColor" => "#999999",
                  "divLineIsDashed" => "1",
                  "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0"
                  )
               );

            $arrData["data"] = array();

    // Push the data into the array
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
               array_push($arrData["data"], array(
                  "label" => $row["date"],
                  "value" => $row["avgtemp"]
                  )
               );
            }

            /*JSON Encode the data to retrieve the string containing the JSON representation of the data in the array. */

            $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);

    /*Create an object for the column chart using the FusionCharts PHP class constructor. Syntax for the constructor is ` FusionCharts("type of chart", "unique chart id", width of the chart, height of the chart, "div id to render the chart", "data format", "data source")`. Because we are using JSON data to render the chart, the data format will be `json`. The variable `$jsonEncodeData` holds all the JSON data for the chart, and will be passed as the value for the data source parameter of the constructor.*/

            $lineChart = new FusionCharts("line", "myFirstChart" , 600, 300, "chart-1", "json", $jsonEncodedData);

            // Render the chart
            $lineChart->render();

            // Close the database connection
            $dbhandle->close();
         }

      ?>

      <div id="chart-1"><!-- Fusion Charts will render here--></div>

   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is your problem? There's a lot of code here and not much in the way of explaining your precise goal.

Comment: I'm trying to get another set of data to graph itself. As you can see, I've got two SQL queries being run, one for the average temperature and one for the average humidity. The average temperature renders perfectly fine, but I cannot seem to get another line (for humidity) to populate. I think the area that I would need to tweak would be near the first reference to $arrData. I've done some minor tweaks and things to see if it will load the second set of data, but have yet to have any success.

Comment: You need to look for JSON structure for the multi series line chart (msline). It seems you are using single series.

Comment: I had recently been looking at some documentation for msline concerning FusionCharts. So I'll be messing with JSON, then? I'm quite new to this graph generator (having come from JPGraph and pChart) so I'm slowly learning all of the different features and extensibility it has. 

So, if you could at least point me in the right direction, that would be great. How do I go about doing multi-series via JSON?